# pass interface object to a custom component via ngFor

Tags: angular

I am having difficulty accomplishing this. My child component has the following:

ChildComonponent

```
     @Input() record : InterfaceRecord;
```

Where InterfaceRecord is:

```
     export interface InterfaceRecord {
            title : string;
          }
```

InterfaceRecords:

```
  export interface InterfaceRecords {
         records : InterfaceRecord[];
         issuedOn: Date;
    }
```

ParentComponent

```
 const records : InterfaceRecord = [];
   const recordsInfo : InterfaceRecords = await someApi.getData();
   records = recordsInfo.records;
```

ParentComponent.html

```
 <app-record-info *ngFor="let r in records" record={{r}}></app-record-info>
```

in my child component, record is [object Object] and I cant access any of its properties. But I can access a records info if I do the following:

```
<app-record-info *ngFor="let r in records" title={{r.title}}></app-record-info>
```

Why cant I access title from record.title in my child component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update this line:

```html
 <app-record-info *ngFor="let r in records" record={{r}}></app-record-info>
```

into:

```html
 <app-record-info *ngFor="let r in records" [record]="r"></app-record-info>
```

`record={{r}}` - record receives `string` value and `r` is an object so you get that string `[object Object]`